# SpringBoot variable injection error. Error Statement: Required type:javax.management.relation.Role

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm using SpringBoot 3.2.2 and implementing social login using OAuth2.
While writing CustomOAuth2UserService, an error occurred in the process of setting permissions.
Below is the body of the code.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomOAuth2UserService implements OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private static final String NAVER="naver";
    private static final String KAKAO="kakao";

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        log.info("CustomOAuth2UserService.loadUser() Run - Enter OAuth2 login request");

/*
* Create a DefaultOAuth2UserService object, create a DefaultOuth2User object through loadUser(userRequest), and return it
* The loadUser() of the DefaultOAuth2UserService sends a request to the user information provider URI of the social login API
* After obtaining user information, create a DefaultOAuth2User object through it and return it.
* As a result, the OAuth2User contains user information obtained from the OAuth service
*/
        OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> delegate = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);

/*
* Extract registrationId from userRequest and save SocialType to registrationId
* * http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/kakao에서 kakao가 registrationId
* The userNameAttributeName is later set to nameAttributeKey.
*/

        String registrationId = userRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId();
        SocialType socialType = getSocialType(registrationId);
        String userNameAttributeName = userRequest.getClientRegistration()
                .getProviderDetails().getUserInfoEndpoint().getUserNameAttributeName();
        // The value that becomes the key (PK) at the time of OAuth2 login

        Map<String, Object> attributes = oAuth2User.getAttributes(); // Json value of userInfo provided by API in social login (user information)

        //  Create OAuthAttributes objects through user information according to socialType
        OAuthAttributes extractAttributes = OAuthAttributes.of(socialType, userNameAttributeName, attributes);

        User createdUser = getUser(extractAttributes, socialType); 

        // Create and return Custom OAuth2User objects that implement DefaultOuth2User
        return new CustomOAuth2User(
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(createdUser.getRole().getKey())),
                attributes,
                extractAttributes.getNameAttributeKey(),
                createdUser.getEmail(),
                createdUser.getRole() //!!!!!error!!!!!
        );
    }
}
```

On the last line,
Required type:javax.management.relation.Role
Provided:com.Next.enums.Role error statement occurs.

In addition, User class block is below

```
package com.Next.domain;

import com.Next.enums.SocialType;
import com.Next.enums.Role;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Entity
@Builder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long id;

    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String nickname;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SocialType socialType; // KAKAO, NAVER, GOOGLE

    private String socialId; // Identifier value of the logged-in social type

    private String refreshToken;//refrsh token

    //user authorize method: GUEST,USER.-->enumerated
    //Initial login-> GUEST, after additional info->update to USER 
    public void authorizeUser() {
        this.role = com.Next.enums.Role.USER;
    }

    //password Encoding method
    public void passwordEncode(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
        this.password=passwordEncoder.encode(this.password);
    }

    public void updateRefreshToken(String updateRefreshToken){
        this.refreshToken=updateRefreshToken;
    }

}
```

I was expecting 'getRole()' import User's Role. I don't know why the user class email is called normally, but the role is not called. I'd appreciate it if you could help me!!

Comment: Check the import statements in CustomOAuth2UserService class. It looks like you have an import of User from javax.management there instead of your com.Next.domain.User